# Coded UI - Is there an HtmlControl to click ng-click button class?

Tags: angularjs, vb.net, coded-ui-tests

Attempting to click a button

[Ng-click  html sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XInqL.png)
I've tried a HtmlDiv trying to find the button with class/type. Not having any luck. Can't find the control. Has anyone had any experience searching for the ng-click? I feel that is my only option at this point. Thanks in advance. Written coded ui in vb.

Public Sub Logout()
            Dim button As New HtmlButton(newbrowser)
            button.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Class, "btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-btn-text", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains)
        End Sub

Nothing will find the control that I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

To mention first, you need to actually match the control. Have you used `FindMatchingControls` (check what the collection contains), `DrawHighlight`, or `TryFind` against the button?

I would also recommend set the scope closer to likely candidates by using an `HtmlDocument` and then a relevant `HtmlDiv`. Also use ID's on your controls, it greatly helps with matching.

Then double check the usual click method does or does not work. Else like below should work well.

After that sometimes I use this helper method

VB

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Shared Function RunScript(control As HtmlControl, script As String) As Object
    Dim bw = TryCast(control.TopParent, BrowserWindow)
    Return bw.ExecuteScript(script, control)
End Function
```

C#

```
public static object RunScript(this HtmlControl control, string script)
{
    var bw = control.TopParent as BrowserWindow;
    return bw.ExecuteScript(script, control);
}
```

Now as for what you actually use for the script value is valid `JS`

```
"arguments[0].click();"
```

Is what I use for clicking some finicky controls. `arguments[0]` is your control you pass in, so from there use `JS` to invoke your special click handler.

You can also use the return statement for pulling back values in with `JS`